# How to redirect to a particular block of html page?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm working on a simple project which has a requirement to show a particular block of html by passing an div id to that url.
I have tried so many solutions, but none of them worked for me.
Here is my code.

```
<div class="row">
    <a onclick="redirect_tooltip();">
        <i class="fa fa-question-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Whenever I click the icon it calls a Javascript function, through that function I tried to pass a url with another page division id

```
function redirect_tooltip()
{
   var source_type = $("#_src_type").val();
   if(source_type == "source")
   {
       window.location.replace(base_url+'/help/tooltip#rtmp_4');
       //I have already difined the base url    
   }
}
```

My html code:

```
<div id="rtmp_4">  
    <h4>Some Title</h4>
    <h5> <?php echo trim($tooltip_rtmp_server[1]);?></h5>
    <p> <?php echo trim($tooltip_rtmp_server[3]);?> </p>
    <h5> <?php echo trim($tooltip_rtmp_stream_name[1]);?></h5>
    <p> <?php echo trim($tooltip_rtmp_stream_name[3]);?> </p>
</div>
```

I need to display only the `rtmp` block whenever the url executes. Please give me a suggestions like where I am doing the mistake.

Comment: what issue are you getting? Does the url redirect on the page you specified?

Comment: redirection is happening but not to a particular block

Comment: can you show your rendered HTML not this php included html?Also do you have multiple `rtmp_4` divs?If yes then show them(at-least two of them)

Comment: yeah i have multiple blocks in the same page but all blocks have diffrent id

Comment: <div id="udpblock">            
                <h4>UDP</h4>
                <h5> <?php echo trim($tooltip_address[1]);?></h5>
                <p> <?php echo trim($tooltip_address[2]);?> </p>
                <h5> <?php echo trim($tooltip_port[1]);?></h5>
                <p> <?php echo trim($tooltip_port[3]);?> </p>
                <h5> <?php echo trim($tooltip_interface[1]);?></h5>
                <p> <?php echo trim($tooltip_interface[3]);?> </p>
            </div>

Comment: i asked for the rendered html on browser not this php included html. Also add in your question not in comment.